# How to remove shadow root (shadow dom) on vue web component creation

Tags: vue.js, web-component, shadow-dom

When creating web component from a vue project using the following command,

```
npm run build -- --target wc --name v-card src\App.vue
```

It creates a shadow root by default. Is there any way to build the web component without the shadow root ?

Comment: same issue, have you found a way?